# Difference between `\textthing` and `$\thing$`?

Tags: math-mode, textcomp

The `textcomp` package provides a lot of symbols for text mode that are also available in math mode. Is there a difference whether I write `\textrightarrow` or `$\rightarrow$`?

Comment: Yes. One symbol is taken from a text font, the other one from a math font.

Comment: Though they might happen to be the same. So the output *might* not be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what font packages you load.

If you load `textcomp`, the characters used *might* be from a different font (using TS1 encoding). Others are only defined if `textcomp` is loaded, which is the case of `\textrightarrow` (provided the font provides it): there is no default definition for it and it is only defined if `textcomp` is loaded.

In other cases, a fallback is built: this happens for `\textcopyright`, which is built from a c and a circle when `textcomp` is not loaded: this package provides (or should provide) a single glyph for it. Another example is `\textbullet` which is taken from the math font, by default, but becomes its own glyph when `textcomp` is loaded.

There are other packages that define more `\text...` commands.